# IOS Orientation fix doesn't work all the time

Tags: ios, orientation, gallery

I am developping a swipe gallery for mobile devices. Users can change images by sliding the screen, as any normal images gallery in most iPhone app.

Here is a demo: 
http://daviddarx.com/stuffs/work/custom/swip/

To debug the iOS orientation bug (which let the content zoomed when you change the orientation), I used the only library that correct that: 
http://scottjehl.github.com/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix/

Unfortunately, this library is working perfectly most of the time, but it happens to fail and not work correctly. This happen around 1 time on 10 times, and the result is then the same as if the library wasn't here.

This is not a huge problem on most of the mobile and responsive website, as the user can manually dezoom and then get back to the normal display.

But the problem here is that I had to disable the zoom function, to make my system work correctly. So, when the bug happen, once on 10 times, the gallery is then just bugged and stay like that....

So, here are my questions:

-do you know any other library that manage that bug fix, and is 100% completely reliable?

-if not, do you know a way to correct the used library to get a 100% support rate?

-if not, do you have any idea or solution for me?

Thank you in advance for your help!
David

Comment: maybe the dev can help you out: https://github.com/scottjehl/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix , a quick fix would be to add 'maximum-scale=1' to your meta

Answer (score 0):

There's an outstanding pull request on Scott Jehl's repo that uses slope detection instead of absolute values which seems to not suffer from the intermittent-ness of the original solution.

https://github.com/PeterWooster/iOS-Orientationchange-Fix/